# Which attacks from enemy heroes makes it possible to deny allied heroes?

Tags: heroes-of-newerth

When playing HoN I often deny ally's when they are have Dots (Damage over time) on them. As an example you can deny if a hero got little HP and have Slithers "Q"-Spell on them...

But yesterday i played and i couldn't deny an ally that had Blood Hunters Ulti on him.(less then 10% HP when i tried to deny). So that made me wounder.

***Which attacks/dots from enemy heroes makes it possible to deny allied heroes?***

**EDIT:**
Still the question remains which spells counts as a dot, is there something that distinguishes regular spells and dots.(Something that would be visible, or is this more of a "general knowledge" question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well they definitely have to affected by a DoT (BH ulti is not a DoT, his silence is though). However, I believe there are exceptions to this. For example I believe it's impossible to deny an ally affected by Voodoo Jester's cursed ground even though AFAIK it's a DoT.

Comment: That is very true, in my mind i think Cursed Ground is very overpowered, in many cases some solid hits after Cursed ground and 1 spell is enough to take down an enemy. Still the question remains which spells counts as a dot, is there something that distinguishes regular spells and dots.(Something that would be visible, or is this more of a "general knowledge" question)

Comment: I believe VJ's curse is the only exception. All other Dots (hag haunt, slither's skills, salforis ulti, bh silence) should be deniable. Check out this forum post where they talk about Vj cursed ground http://forums.heroesofnewerth.com/showthread.php?136886-1-0-8-Cursed-ground-(voodoo-jester)

Comment: Also just to re-iterate, BH ulti is not a DoT (his first skill is though)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% on this, but I believe it has to be a lethal dot. In that instance, he isn't taking damage unless he's moving, so he isn't technically receiving lethal damage.

If BH has his silence/dot on him, however, and it would tick for enough to kill him, I believe that would then open up the opportunity to deny the affected hero.

More knowledgeable players, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but, BH's Ulti still does damage even if you're standing still. Besides as far as I know Slithers ulti can't kill you but it's still possible to deny heroes that have slither's ulti on them.

Comment: I'd love to know the end-all ruling on this, because I'm always blocking people when I try to deny them, only to find out I can't and simply get them killed quicker ;x

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the standard attack/target command, to my understanding.

According to hon.gamepedia.com: It is also possible to deny heroes. An ally hero can be denied if he has less than 10% health and is affected by a DoT. Enemy heroes will not receive bonus gold and XP for hero kills, but will still gain the default gold and XP bonus for being within 1000 units within the dead hero. You can also use allied non-hero units to deny heroes.

Comment: I also looked up BH's ultimate a little closer: it does cause initial damage, but there is no true dot. It's damage you take only when you move, but not periodic as with a traditional damage over time spell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, +1 for link to hon.gamepedia.com, and generally a good comment.